# how to avoid vertical scrollbar in horizontal slider layout

Tags: html, css

I will try to create a slider(move to left or right), but when I set outer Container(.wrapper) width over `100vw` and set the height to `100vh` with every child div, It will overflow on vertical, how can I avoid it?

[Open the detailed description of the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRPwz.png)

```css
body{
  padding : 0;
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  width : 200vw;  
}

.section {
  width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

.section1 {
  background-color : red;
}

.section2{
  background-color : yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section section1">1</div>
  <div class="section section2">2</div>
</div>
```

[if you want to edit with online editor, you can try it](https://jsfiddle.net/30yupo0n/)

---

and I don't know why if When I only have one child div(.section), the height doesn't vertical overflow(move up and down)

```css
body{
  padding : 0;
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  width : 100vw;  
}

.section {
  width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

.section1 {
  background-color : red;
}
/*
.section2 {
  background-color : yellow;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section section1">1</div>
  <!--<div class="section section1">1</div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Check this link for more infor. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question says you're looking to hide the **horizontal** scrollbar (left and right), your image indicates that you're actually looking to hide the **vertical** scrollbar (up and down).

You're looking to add **[`overflow-y: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)** to `body` in order to hide the vertical scrollbar:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 200vw;
}

.section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section section1">1</div>
  <div class="section section2">2</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you are indeed looking to hide the *horizontal* scrollbar, this can be done with **[`overflow-x: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)**, though note that your content won't actually be too tall to escape the bounds vertically with the horizontal scrollbar removed. Setting a height of `110vh` demonstrates this working:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 200vw;
}

.section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 110vh;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section section1">1</div>
  <div class="section section2">2</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks, you got my mean!! and I have other question about when I only have one child It will success that vertical didn't overflow

Comment: you can see detail at the bottom of the original question

Comment: No problem! The second question about the element not overflowing is covered briefly in my answer. You're setting a `height` of `100vh`. When there's a horizontal scrollbar, it takes up some of the height. As such the **horizontal** scrollbar makes the element overflow **vertically** (because there is less than `100%` of the height when the horizontal scrollbar is there). When there's no horizontal scrollbar, the content fits perfectly within the bounds of `100vh` (it doesn't actually overflow at all). Hope that helps clarify :)

Comment: **[open sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/j92wknw8/)** If I can't change styles of body, Is the only way to put them in a new div and set `overflow-y`?